# Is it possible to detect and (automatically or manually) reload a crashing DLL in a JNI-based Java application

Tags: java, c, crash, java-native-interface

I'm working with an application, based on Java and C/C++, the link between both is JNI. The C/C++ is compiled into a DLL. So, we have following Java source code:

```
System.loadLibrary(<product.DLL>);
<Complete algorithm, filled with JNI calls>
```

Regularly we have crashes in the C/C++ code, because of which the algorithm stops.

In order to handle this, I could enter exception handling in the C/C++ code, and have those forwarded to the Java code, in order to be handled as Java exceptions. Like this, I could avoid crashes, but there is one important catch: my application is around thirty years old, some tens of developpers have worked on it during this time (±2 million lines of source code), in other words the application has become far too big to implement exception handling on every JNI call.

Therefore I start wondering: would the following be possible:

```
System.loadLibrary(<product.DLL>);
try {
  <Complete algorithm, filled with JNI calls>
catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println("An exception occured: " + e.getMessage());
  System.reloadLibrary(<product.DLL>);
}
```

And once such a problem occurs, the application simply goes further to the next processing. My first guess is that I'm being too naïve here, but even then: my application is running over a series of data, is it possible to catch a crash and reload the DLL on a particular place in the Java source code?

Comment: Can you reveal what the library is?

Comment: The library is the product DLL, created by my company, it's not a generic DLL.

Comment: Crashes are caused by memory corruption - the DLL is broken.  The fix isn't to ignore the problem and try again - it's to **fix the broken code**.  If the wheel fell off your car every 10 minutes, would you (1) fix it, or (2) keep driving, replacing the wheel every time it fell off?  Your wheels keep falling off, and you're proposing it's OK to just keep driving.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: let me explain you the background: I'm responsible for a testlist, checking if our application is working fine. This testlist opens the DLL once and launches all individual tests, but if one of those tests fails (in the sense of crashing the DLL), all other tests are not executed anymore. I realise this is due to a wrong design of the test application (it should load the DLL every time a test is to be performed), but you can imagine that re-designing the test application is a big deal, hence my question.

Comment: Is it a C++ exception? (For that matter, is it C or C++?) Please show the crash error message and a minimal, complete, verifiable example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When C/C++ code crashes the process this is not recoverable without restarting the process. I suggest you have a Java process which starts a second JVM to load the DLL and if that fails, try again